# functions inside array to ignore the array's scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a constructor and am trying to have an array of functions inside its prototype, but i need the functions to have the scope of the object created by the constructor, and not the array's scope.
I tried using .bind(this) or .bind(_p) but "this" is the node server's scope and _p is just the prototype without the variables.

```
function BoardModel() {
    this.x = 3
    this.y = 2
}

_p = BoardModel.prototype;

_p.skillFunctions = [
    function(){
        console.log(this.x); //undefined
    },
    function(){
        console.log(this.y); //undefined
    },
];
```

Comment: If you want to use these functions for any object created with the constructor then why not just pass the object reference to them?

Comment: you mean whenever i call any of the functions to just pass the object as a parameter? that's possible i guess, was hoping for a more natural solution.

Comment: ©Maayan Blum You can just add those functions to the prototype like any other method and have a property on the prototype (or the created object if you want customization) containing an array of function names you want to call. Then you just iterate over the array and call the method like `this[methodName]();`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an own method for each property, instead of an array?

```js
function BoardModel() {
    this.x = 3
    this.y = 2
}

_p = BoardModel.prototype;

_p.skillFunctionsX = function (){
    console.log(this.x);
};

_p.skillFunctionsY = function (){
    console.log(this.y);
};

var item = new BoardModel;
item.skillFunctionsX();
item.skillFunctionsY();
```

Comment: I need to be able to call them by index.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions use this from the enclosing context so how about this (pun intended)?

```
function BoardModel() {
    this.x = 3
    this.y = 2

    this.skillFunctions = [
       () => { console.log(this.x) },
       () => { console.log(this.y) },
    ];
}

let board = new BoardModel()

board.skillFunctions.forEach((skillFunction) => { skillFunction() })
```

Comment: this way the functions are created every time the constructor is called. i tried using arrow functions inside the _p.skillFunctions[ ] but the scope was still the array's scope.

Comment: @MaayanBlum Well, yes, the arrow functions in the array will have "this" set to the enclosing context, which would be the global object (or undefined in strict mode) in our example. You cannot do what you imagined exactly the way you imagined. However, you could create the individual functions directly on the prototype, as Nina suggested, keep an array of the function names, iterate over it and invoke the functions. Alternatively, you can pass in the context.